# How to enable "on-the-fly" autocompletion with vim-supertab?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Using the "supertab" plugin for autocompletion in vim, how can I make it so that hitting TAB is not required for the selection menu to pop up?

I.e. what I want is the menu to be always present and to be constantly updating its suggestions as I type.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: Will do, thank you.